# Deployed Maven project to Tomcat 7, still getting 404

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a Maven web project in Eclipse, I managed to resolve all errors and succesfuly deployed it into my Tomcat7 server, but I'm still getting the 404 Resource not found error when I try to go to `http://localhost:8080/projecteBase/`

I get no errors when I build the project using `clean tomcat7:redeploy`

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ projecteBase ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ projecteBase ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ projecteBase ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ projecteBase ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [projecteBase] in [C:\Eclipse\workspace\projecteBase\target\projecteBase]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Eclipse\workspace\projecteBase\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [785 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Eclipse\workspace\projecteBase\target\projecteBase.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ projecteBase <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ projecteBase ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/projecteBase  
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FprojecteBase&update=true
Uploaded: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FprojecteBase&update=true (22897 KB at 51919.6 KB/sec)

[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
[INFO] OK - Desplegada aplicaciÃ³n en trayectoria de contexto /projecteBase
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.500 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-20T16:08:30-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/44M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I get no errors on the tomcat log (besides the LOCALE one, which shouldn't mater):

```
oct 20, 2015 4:17:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Información: Manager: deploy: Deploying web application '/projecteBase'
oct 20, 2015 4:17:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Información: Manager: Uploading WAR file to C:\Eclipse\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\webapps\projecteBase.war.tmp
oct 20, 2015 4:17:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Información: Despliegue del archivo C:\Eclipse\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\webapps\projecteBase.war de la aplicación web
oct 20, 2015 4:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Información: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
16:17:18,657        ERROR LocaleUtils:50 - Locale name null or empty, ignoring
oct 20, 2015 4:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Información: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
oct 20, 2015 4:17:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Información: Deployment of web application archive C:\Eclipse\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\webapps\projecteBase.war has finished in 4.173 ms
```

My plugin configuration in the pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      <server>tomcat7</server>
      <path>/projecteBase</path>
      <username>adminscript</username>
      <password>adminscript</password>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've tried several possible solutions I found on the web but I still can't seem to correctly deploy it. Any idea what could be the problem? Let me know if you need to see another file or log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to tomcat console and click list applications and there must be a start or launch button for your application. it should open the right page

Comment: on the other hand, it is not clear what your app does. If you don't have an index.html or index.jsp you'll be getting 404.

Answer (score 0):

A rapid look in your tomcat logs raised an error:

```
Información: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
16:17:18,657        ERROR LocaleUtils:50 - Locale name null or empty, ignoring
```

It is often a tomcat's reason to undeploy the application for security reasons and serve a 404 document.

Look at your library dependencies too. A good definition of them inside your pom.xml can change your world.